# Whether performBlockAndWait calling twice on single thread cause deadlock?

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data

I have found something like this in `performBlockAndWait` documentation:

> This method may safely be called reentrantly.

My question is whether it means that it never cause deadlock when I e.g. will invoke it like that on single context?:

```
NSManageObjectContext *context = ...

[context performBlockAndWait:^{
       // ... some stuff

       [context performBlockAndWait:^{

       }];
 }];
```

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11833139/1971013) help?

Comment: so this means that my code do not provide deadlock

Comment: IMHO, that above answer in the link given in the comment by @meaning-matters, is at least misleading - if not  wrong. The correct answer to the above question is, that in case of dispatch_sync, dispatch lib _may_ apply an optimisation which uses the _current_ thread to execute the block. Note though, that the block is actually executing in the _specified_ queue. Dispatch lib can choose whatever thread to execute a block on a certain queue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try it yourself with a small code snippet ;)

But true, it won't deadlock.

I suspect, the internal implementation uses a queue specific token in order to identify the current queue on which the code executes (see `dispatch_queue_set_specific` and `dispatch_queue_get_specific`).

If it determines that the current executing code executes on its own private queue or on a children-queue, it simply bypasses submitting the block synchronously - which would cause a dead-lock, and instead executing it directly.

A possible implementation my look as below:

```
func executeSyncSafe(f: () -> ()) {
    if isSynchronized() {
        f()
    } else {
        dispatch_sync(syncQueue, f)
    }
}

func isSynchronized() -> Bool {
    let context = UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>(Unmanaged<dispatch_queue_t>.passUnretained(syncQueue).toOpaque())
    return dispatch_get_specific(&queueIDKey) == context 
}
```

And the queue might be created like this:

```
private var queueIDKey = 0  // global


init() {
    dispatch_queue_attr_make_with_qos_class(DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL,
            QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE, 0))
    let context = UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>(Unmanaged<dispatch_queue_t>.passUnretained(syncQueue).toOpaque())
    dispatch_queue_set_specific(syncQueue, &queueIDKey, context, nil)
}
```

`dispatch_queue_set_specific` associates a *token* (here `context` - which is simply the pointer value of the queue) with a certain *key* for that queue. And later, you can try to retrieve that token for any queue specifying the *key* and check whether the current queue is the same queue or a children-queue. If this is true, bypass dispatching to the queue and instead call the function `f` directly.

Comment: I'm asking whether my code in question is safe because in my application code I have nested "performBlockAndWait" on given context, to get rid of this nested structure I would have to refactor major piece of my existing code (and as we know it can brings some bugs ...). But if it is ok and core data will handle with this without deadlock I will leave this code as it is.

Comment: @roher Your code won't dead-lock. So, it's save to have nested calls to `performBlockAndWait` which use the same queue. However, synchronously submitting code to queues will always be more prone to dead-locks. Avoid it, if you can - and there's always a way to implement it in a pure asynchronous style.

Comment: Thank you for your all explanation, in my situation it is required to do some sequential operations on core data, so i need to perform block and wait on core data context.