# Unexpected Core Data Multithreading Violation

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, core-data, swift3

I'm using Apple's concurrency core data debugger.

> -com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1

From time to time I got `__Multithreading_Violation_AllThatIsLeftToUsIsHonor__`, even I'm almost sure threading is not violated.

This is part of code where exception occurs (code is part of protocol that extends NSManagedObject):

```
public static func find(arrayBy predicate: NSPredicate, sort: [NSSortDescriptor] = [], limit: Int? = nil) -> [Self] {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Self>(entityName: "\(Self.self)")
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sort

    do {
        return try Context.current.fetch(fetchRequest) // Exception!!!
    } catch let error {
        Logger.fatal("Failed to perform fetch: \(error)")
        return []
    }
}
```

Code is executed within context's `perform:` block.

Here is thread information:

[image]

and debuger info to confirm that perform is executed on the right NSManagedContext:

```
(lldb) po Context.current
<StoreContext: 0x7f854b556610>
```

Entity name is extracted successfully:

```
po fetchRequest.entityName!
"Position"
```

Predicate is constructed of pure String objects (no managed objects used at all):

```
(lldb) po fetchRequest.predicate!
ANY employees.company.id == "282372"
```

Sort descriptors are not used at all in this case:

```
po fetchRequest.sortDescriptors!
0 elements
```

Limit is completely ignored.

What am I missing? Does anyone has any idea what can be wrong here?

**Edit:**

To clarify, `Context.current` is set just before dispatching the block:

```
Context.current = managedObjectContext
managedObjectContext.performAndWait {
   //...
}
```

You can see on the screenshot that `Thread 13` is running on `Queue: NSManagedObject 0x7f854b556610 (serial)`. Also, when exception occurs `Context.current` returns `<StoreContext: 0x7f854b556610>`. By looking at the memory address it's easy to conclude block is executing on the right queue.

Comment: can you try with `com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1` flag and see if you find anything?

Comment: I'm already using it, that is why multithreading violation exception is raised.

Comment: what is `Context.current`?  why aren't you use the managedObject own context (`self.managedObjectContext`)?

Comment: Because I don't have managed object instance. This is class method and objects are instantiated during successful fetch. `Context.current` is the class field with cached `managedObjectContext` during `perform` call. That's not a problem, debug info shows that thread queue and context are same.

Comment: Can you share the code for `Context.current`? How do you know that's returning the correct context for the current thread?

Comment: Take a look at the post edit.

Comment: I know that the predicate _looks_ like it only has a string NOW as you stated in your question, but did you use a managedObject in building the predicate? Is that managedObject on the correct thread?

Comment: I'm passing string variable to `NSPredicate(format:)`. `managedObject` is used to initialize variable like `let id = managedObject.id`, but at that point no exception occurred and I check that it is on correct thread.

Comment: What is `StoreContext`? Did you subclass `NSManagedObjectContext`? Documentation strongly discourages subclassing contexts. Try replacing this call with standard CoreData code, spin off new `NSManagedObjectContext` and run `performBlock`. There is no point of returning array of objects when they are outside of context anyway. You should be safe passing `NSManagedObjectIDs` around.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html

Comment: @XeNoN what was your final solution?

Answer (score 4):

Storing the "current" background context in a global state is a bad practice.  I can't point out where exactly in your code it is messing up, but unexpected things can happen with global state when multithreading is involved.  Change your `find` function to accept a `context` as a parameter.  This will avoid using any global state and is will likely fix your problem.

Comment: I agree, but in this particular case protocol is used to achieve active record pattern (method return value type is `[Self]`) and adding context as parameter make no sense. Debug info shows that problem isn't directly related to execution on the wrong queue. I'm starting to guess there is a problem somewhere else in my code but exception occurs here due invalid core data graph (some objects in existing graph may be from another context).

Comment: Each `NSManagedObject` has a pointer to the `managedObjectContext` that is is associated with.

Comment: Your code sets `Context.current` and then calls `performAndWait`, which is fine in isolation. However, it's mutable global state, there is nothing to protect `Context.current` from being changed while the `performAndWait` is working. I'm not that familiar with Ruby, but doesn't it largely single-threaded? If you wanted to maintain the simplicity of your current interface, maybe you can just enforce that everything happens on the main thread.

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment.

Comment: @DaveWeston I think you mistakenly went into Swift thread. It's not Ruby question...

Comment: The original poster mentioned active record pattern, so I immediately went to ActiveRecord from Rails. The point is that patterns that work in one framework with particular characteristics might not work in other frameworks when those characteristics change. With pervasive multithreading, you can't just store a value somewhere and then expect to get the same value back somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

It is *recommended* to avoid using the `.performAndWait` API, to be used only at the rarest of the rare occasions, when everything else has [*failed!*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32214574/3339346)
Evaluate morphing `Context.current` to `managedObjectContext.perform` *throughout* the application.
The effect of this change would be addition of asynchronicity in *all* your database operations.
It may sound of a *massive* change to ask for but trust me, just decide to treat Core Data as a completely asynchronous API & life will be much better this way.
I'm sure the current crash you are facing is a result of compound result of the corrupted behavior of `.performAndWait`

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32198678/behavior-differences-between-performblock-and-performblockandwait), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922145/what-is-nsmanagedobjectcontexts-performblock-used-for) and [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html) are some good reads on the topic.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this blog to get better understanding of multithreading in Core Data

https://cocoacasts.com/core-data-and-concurrency/

https://cocoacasts.com/more-core-data-and-concurrency/